# SyncAdapter android:userVisible attribute not working

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

According to the android Documentation

> **android:userVisible** defaults to true and controls whether or not this sync adapter shows up in the Sync Settings screen.

but it shows in the Settings whatever value it gets!

**EDIT Nov 03 2014**

I removed **android:icon** **android:label** **android:smallIcon** from `authenticator.xml` and now it's not showing in the Accounts but there is an empty entry on Add Account tested on Samsung Galaxy S4. And for the record this totally crashed my 2.3.3 emulator when opening Accounts from Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented my own syncadapter it's working for me as below :

Case 1:   When  `android:userVisible="false"` There is only **app icon,Account name and app title**

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:contentAuthority="com.example.kukssyncadapter"
              android:accountType="com.example.kukssyncadapter"
               android:supportsUploading="false"
              android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
          android:userVisible="false" 
        />
```

[image]

Case 2:   When  `android:userVisible="true"` There is  **app icon,Account name and app title with sync control functionality as you can see from image**

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:contentAuthority="com.example.kukssyncadapter"
              android:accountType="com.example.kukssyncadapter"
               android:supportsUploading="false"
              android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
          android:userVisible="true" 
        />
```

[image]

Comment: and there is no way to hide it completely?

Comment: What you mean hide it completely ? Are you saying hide icon,account...everything

Comment: Then refer this it can help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562432/hide-dummy-account-for-sync-adapter-from-settings

Comment: I checked that before asking the question but unfortunately there is no answers.